# Bootstrap social share button

Tags: html, css, social-networking

I'm trying to add some social share buttons on my blog with Bootstrap, but I'm not getting how to put the URL from the site after the link of the Twitter `/share`.

This is the code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="btn btn-social btn-twitter">
                  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Share on Twitter</i>
</a>
```

---------- Edited:
Now it's half working.
I've made a function that open a popup, the link-in-popup:

```
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" class="btn btn-social btn-facebook link-in-popup">
     <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Share on Facebook</i>
 </a>
```

But only open the link "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u", how do I get the url of the page after the "u"? Twitter itself opens the popup with the link, but not facebook. I need something like " `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[URLPAGE]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working completely!

Here's the code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo(($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>" class="btn btn-social btn-facebook link-in-popup">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Share on Facebook</i>
</a>
```

The php gets the current url. I'm just finding out a way to this whole php code turns into a variable. Thank you all!

Comment: If anyone finds this, don't use this answer. This code is vulnerable to XSS. And `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://` is a bit silly. Just use // and the browser will know to use the same protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter has a section on its website which documents how to get their various buttons to function. This is available at https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons.

Assuming you already have Twitter's sharing `script` element included on your page, to link your Tweet button to a custom URL you need to introduce a `data-url` attribute on your `a` element:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="..." data-url="http://example.com">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Share on Twitter</i>
</a>
```

If you don't have this `script` element included on your page then I suggest you generate the button through the page I've linked to above and modify it after copying the HTML it generates there for you.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the `</a>`.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="btn btn-social btn-twitter">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Share on Twitter</i> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do it is like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Share on Twitter</i>
</a>
```

This is the common skeleton. The class and data-url depends on you. If you do not specify data-url, then you are going to share the current url. Check this link [demo](http://sanmarx2.eu5.org/examples/TwitterButtonsBootstrap/) to see a working example and the different sizes and styles you can construct depending on the class.

Just in case you didn't know, Twitter provides a [Tweet Button](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button), which is a small widget that allows users to easily share your website with their followers.

Twitter provides a [quick way](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons) to build a Tweet Button for your website. You can easily customize your tweet button, and then copy paste the code. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/hpmg2ud0/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!